# Background color of social media links extends to other links and overlaps them

Tags: html, css

I want to contain the teal hover within the borders of my social media links. I’ve tried adjusting the padding and heights and widths via CSS properties but when hovering, it still overlaps over the right border.

This is what it looks like while not hovering:

[image: Three black boxes with icons]

This is what it looks like when hovering:

[image: The first box has a teal background, but the background extends to the second box]

The image sizes are each 19px × 15px.

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  left: 1.4em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  float: right;
  z-index: 200;
}

#boxlist li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: -2.5em;
  float: left;
}

.imgli:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 1);
}

.imgli {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
  padding-right: 4em;
}

.imgli:first-child {
  left: -0.1em;
  border: none;
}

.imgli:nth-child(2) {
  left: 1em;
}

.imgli:nth-child(3) {
  left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="box">
    <ul id="boxlist">
      <li class="imgli"><img src="images/banner-social-icon-twitter.png" class="boximg"></li>
      <li class="imgli"><img src="images/banner-social-icon-facebook.png" class="boximg"></li>
      <li class="imgli"><img src="images/banner-social-icon-email.png" class="boximg"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VVj3R/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlapping is happening, I believe, because of the 
margin-left:-2.5em combined with the fixed width of the container, you are still experiencing overlap, despite the fact that your elements are floating.
Without doing a detailed lookover of your layout, one solution is to apply a background color to your `<li>`s to prevent the overlap, see the update I made to your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VVj3R/1/

I just added the background line to `.imgli`'s definition and it seems to work.

```
.imgli {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(153,153,153,1);
    padding-right:4em;
    background-color:black;
}
```

You may want to change black to something else, as long as its an opaque color.

PS the images didn't show up in your fiddle because you used relative path names.

Comment: ya sorry should have uploaded them. That worked perfectly thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try making your code bit simpler.. like this:

```
<div id="box">
  <ul>
    <li><div class="button" id="btn1"></div></li>
    <li><div class="button" id="btn2"></div></li>
    <li><div class="button" id="btn3"></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#box ul {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0px;  
}

#box li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 1px;  
}

#box .button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px; 
  background-color: #000;  
}

#box .button:hover {
  background-color:rgba(0,255,255,1);  
}

#btn1 {
  background-image: url(someicon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 40px 40px;  
}
```

Here is fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tb2Ug/